Is there a closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(2n+3/2,z)}{n!z^{2n+1/2}}$?
Background
I'm trying to evaluate
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma\left(2n+\frac{3}{2},z\right)}{n!z^{2n+1/2}}.\tag{1}$$
Here, $\gamma{(a,z)}$ denotes the lower incomplete gamma function and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I encountered a similar series during my research and evaluated it successfully; the structure piqued my interest, so I decided to investigate simpler series of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(an+b,z)}{(cn+d)!z^{fn+g}}, \tag{2}$$
where $a,f\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, $b\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$, $c\in\mathbb{N}$, and $d,g\in\mathbb{Q}_{\geq0}$. I've scoured here, Math Overflow, Google, and any reference books I could get my hands on (e.g., The Bateman Manuscript Project, Abramowitz and Stegun, the first three volumes of Prudnikov's, Brychkov's, and Marichev's Integrals and Series, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, etc.), but this family of series doesn't seem to be well-documented or studied. When $an+b\geq fn+g$, specifically if $b=g+k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, I'm fairly certain that $(2)$ can always be analytically continued to be entire; because $\gamma(a,z)=a^{-1}z^a {}_1F_1(a;1+a;-z)$ (see here), these conditions remove the multivaluedness of $\gamma(a,z)$ for non-integer $a$, and $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\gamma(an+b,\,z)}{z^{fn+g}}$ is $\frac{1}{an+b}$ when $an+b=fn+g$ and $0$ otherwise. There quite obviously is no closed form for the general case (if one exists, then it must necessarily be very general, such as Meijer G, and not reduce easily), but I have found some using a method that I noticed when considering the properties of the incomplete gamma functions.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(n+1,z)}{(n+1)!}&=\Gamma(0,z)+\log{(z)}+\gamma \tag{2.1} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(n+1,z)}{n! z^n}&=\frac{z}{z-1}\left(1-e^{1-z}\right) \tag{2.2} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(2n+1,z)}{n! z^n}&=2\sqrt{z}F{\left(\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2}\right)} \tag{2.3} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(2n+1,z)}{n! z^{2n}}&=zF{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}+ze^{1-z}F{\left(1-\frac{z}{2}\right)} \tag{2.4} \\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\gamma\left(n+\frac32,z\right)}{n!z^{n+1/2}}&=\frac{ze^{1-z}}{1-z}\left(1-\frac{F(\sqrt{1-z})}{\sqrt{1-z}}\right) \tag{2.5}
\end{align}
Here, $\Gamma(a,z)=\Gamma(a)-\gamma(a,z)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function, $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, and $F(z)$ denotes the Dawson function (also known as Dawson's integral).
Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\gamma(a,z)=z^{a-1} e^{-z}$ and $\frac{d^n}{dz^n} e^z=e^z$, we can multiply $(2)$ by $e^z$ and use the recurrence relation for the lower incomplete gamma function to craft and solve a linear ODE, then divide by $e^z$ (since it's entire and never $0$) to obtain the target function. There doesn't seem to be a general algorithm for doing so, and the tricks can be a bit elusive; for instance, the easiest method I found to solve $(2.3)$ was showing its equivalence to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2\gamma(2n+2,\,z)}{n! z^{n+1}}$ and using this fact to build the ODE $f'(z)-\left(\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{3}{4}\right)f(z)=\frac{e^z}{2}$.

My Work
Setting $f(z)=e^z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(2n+3/2,z)}{n!z^{2n+1/2}}$ and differentiating, we get
$$f'(z)=f(z)+e-e^z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\gamma\left(2n+\frac{3}{2},z\right)}{n!z^{2n+3/2}}. \tag{3}$$
Adding and subtracting by $f(z)/z$ followed by combining $-f(z)/z$ with the series and using the recurrence relation for $\gamma(a,z)$ gives
$$f'(z)=\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)f(z)-e^z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma\left(2n+\frac{5}{2},z\right)}{n!z^{2n+3/2}}. \tag{4}$$
Alternatively, we can split the series into two to obtain
$$f'(z)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2z}\right)f(z)+e-2e^z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma\left(2n+\frac{7}{2},z\right)}{n!z^{2n+7/2}}\label{4.1}. \tag{4.1}$$
We will use this below. Returning to $(4)$ and differentiating again gives
$$f''(z)=\left(2+\frac{1}{z}\right)f'(z)-\left(1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)f(z)-e+e^z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2n+\frac{3}{2}\right)\gamma\left(2n+\frac{5}{2},z\right)}{n!z^{2n+5/2}}.$$
Adding and subtracting $f'(z)/z$ (from $(4)$) and simplifying, we get
$$f''(z)=\left(2+\frac{2}{z}\right)f'(z)-\left(1+\frac{2}{z}+\frac{2}{z^2}\right)f(z)+e^z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma\left(2n+\frac{7}{2},z\right)}{n!z^{2n+5/2}}. \tag{5}$$
Finally, using $(4.1)$, we can write the ODE
$$f''(z)+\left(\frac{z}{2}-2-\frac{2}{z}\right)f'(z)-\left(\frac{z}{2}-\frac{5}{4}-\frac{2}{z}-\frac{2}{z^2}\right)f(z)=\frac{ez}{2}.\tag{6}$$
Our initial conditions are $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=-\frac{1+i}{2\sqrt{2}}\gamma(3/4,-1)$.

The Problem
The second-order linear ODE in $(6)$ is nasty-looking, and I see no way to approach it; no substitution stands out, and multiplying by any power of $z$ doesn't make one any more visible to me. Wolfram Alpha fails to find a closed form (I don't have access to Mathematica), but it does show that each step is valid numerically. The first ODE I found when solving $(2.4)$ was of the second order as well, $g''(z)+\left(\frac{z}{2}-2\right)g'(z)-\left(\frac{z}{2}-2\right)g(z)=e^z+\frac{ez}{2}-e$, until I tinkered enough and stumbled upon the first-order ODE $g'(z)+\left(\frac{z}{2}-1-\frac{1}{z}\right)g(z)=\frac{z}{2}e^z-\frac{ez}{2}$. I suspect that a first-order ODE exists for $f(z)$, and most likely for every member of $(2)$ that is entire as well, due to the recurrence relation for $\gamma(a,z)$, but my attempts to find one lead back to either $(4)$ or $(4.1)$. Again, I suspect one exists, but the trick to finding it seems very elusive. With all of this in mind, I'll restate my question: is there a closed form for
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma\left(2n+\frac{3}{2},z\right)}{n!z^{2n+1/2}}?$$

Any luck with substituting an integral representation of $\gamma$?

@Aruralreader Furthest I can get tonight is $f(z)=ze^{-z^2/4}\int_0^1\sqrt{t}e^{(t-z/2)^2}dt$. Works numerically but I see no way to progress further. Perhaps I'm just too tired, but it seems like it might need hypergeometric functions.

As for substituting directly into the ODE, $(2.4)$ is a linear combination of two different $\gamma$s, and finding the right combination seems monumental given the jump in complexity between $(2.2)$ and $(2.5)$. While further comparing $(2.2)$ and $(2.5)$, my intuition tells me that the solution might involve the integral of the Dawson function, which is a generalized hypergeometric.

Mathematica can solve the ODE and give general solution

@MariuszIwaniuk Could you post it as an answer? Like I said, I don't have access to Mathematica, only Wolfram Alpha (which fails) and Sage (which has a very limited ODE solving implementation).
